# Use SQL For XML Path or C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to show a grid of contacts and their phone numbers, each contact has sevral phone numbers so I have 2 ways to do it:
1. Use SQL for xml path like this:

```
SELECT contacts.first_name,
       (SELECT SUB.display_phone + ',' AS [text()]
       FROM contact_phones SUB
       WHERE SUB.contact_id = contacts.id
       FOR XML PATH('')) AS Phones
 FROM contacts
```

1. Use sql to get only the contacts into a DataTable, and use a second query to bring all phone numbers to a dictionary and use C# code to attach each contact his phone numbers.

Can someone tell me what approuce has better performance ?

Comment: Try it, and measure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if you can do it in a database - do it.

However, this may depend. If you have very small table, it maybe faster to query an in-memory structure, as you save time you a round trip to a database. On the other hand, if a table is rather large, a database would usually filter it faster, plus it doesn't use compute and memory resources of the local process.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some heavy XML in SQL Server and my experience is that it is terrible slow (even if indexed). I would query all data and then, while filling/constructing the DataTable, parse (using XmlDocument?) and attach the neccessary column.

Anyway, my XML blobs where quite large and complex (1-5mb each), and if smaller, perhaps using the SQL XML feature is better anyway. Sorry this wasn't really an answer :)

Good luck with your query!

Comment: Thanks... I think each way has it's advantage, it depands on how many data I'm pulling out. Right ?